# bazel build error in project containing pcl

Tags: bazel

My WORKSPACE file is below:

```
new_local_repository(
   name = "opencv",
   path = "/usr/local",
   build_file = "opencv.BUILD",
)
new_local_repository(
   name = "pcl",
   path = "/usr/local",
   build_file = "pcl.BUILD"
)
```

my pcl.BUILD file is below:

```
cc_library(
   name = "pcl",
   srcs = glob(["lib/libopencv_*.so*"]),
   hdrs = glob(["include/pcl-1.7/pcl/**/*.hpp", "include/pcl-1.7/pcl/**/*.h"]),
   includes = ["include"],
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
   linkstatic = 1,
)
```

my code is very sample, just like below:

```
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello pcl" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and i run bazel build command, using `bazel query //...` and bazel build target.
now I get the error like "fatal error: pcl/common/common_headers.h: No such file or directory". Why?

Someone can give suggestion for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in the `#include` you must use a path relative to the repository's root:

```
#include "include/pcl-1.7/pcl/common/common_headers.h"
```

In order to be able to include like so:

```
#include "pcl/common/common_headers.h"
```

...I believe you need to change `cc_library.includes` to this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "pcl",
    ...
    includes = ["include/pcl-1.7"],
    ...
)
```

Also, I believe you have to use quotes in `#include`, not angle brackets:

```
#include "pcl/common/common_headers.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But I got the same error even if I use your method.

Comment: Which Bazel version do you use? Mine is 0.16.1 and the solution works for me with that version. What's the output of `bazel build //... --verbose_failures`? (Please update your OP with that info.)